# Why is derivation $D$ on bilinear form $C:V\times V\to K$ is defined as $C(DX,Y)+C(X,DY)=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

This is related to Knapp, Lie groups, Chpt I, Sec 4, Examples 2).

Let $V$ be a vector space over $k$ and $C$ be a bilinear form over $V\times V$. Derivation $D$ on bilinear form $C:V\times V\to K$ is defined as $C(DX,Y)+C(X,DY)=0$ for all $X,Y\in V$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Why do I want $C(DX,Y)+C(X,DY)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition means that the bilinear form is **derivation invariant**, see [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82564775.pdf), and this terminology makes more sense.
For Lie algebras, it corresponds to the fact that the Killing form is *invariant*. It is given by 
$$C(x,y)=tr({\rm ad}(x),{\rm ad}(y))$$ for $x,y\in V$.